# Validate a phone number with C # Regex, that starts with the number 6 or 7

Tags: c#, regex, validation, phone-number

I want to validate this way

- Only digits numeric
- Let the numbers only start with the number 6 or 7

I have tried something like that:

```
public Regex RegexPhoneNumber { get; set; } = new Regex(@"^(\6\7[0-9])$");
```

Comment: `^[67][0-9]{7}$`

Comment: Is it maximum 8 digits or exactly 8 digits? Because "exactly 8" appears to be what you're trying in your sample, and would be a more expected requirement for most phone systems I can think of.

Comment: exactly 8 digits, but the most important thing I want to validate is that it starts with the number 6 or 7

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor Stribiżew,, I'ts working